# Show that $c_nX_n \overset{p}{\to}cX$ if $X_n \overset{p}{\to}X$ and $c_n$ is a sequence of reals which converges to the limit $c \in(0,\infty)$.

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, convergence-divergence

I'm new at this and need help with the following problem:

"Assume $X_n \overset{p}{\to}X$ and $c_n$ is a sequence of reals which converges to the limit $c \in(0,\infty)$. Show that $c_nX_n \overset{p}{\to}cX$."

I got a hint that says that I can start out, as $n \to \infty$, with
$E(|c_nX_n-cX|^r)\le |c_n|^rE(|X_n-X|^r)+|c_n-c|^rE|X^r| \to0$,
by Minkowski's inequality.

---

Minkowski's inequality:

$(E(|X+Y|^r))^{1/r}\le (E(|X|^r))^{1/r}+(E(|Y|))^{1/r}$

---

The hint confuses me, why is it ok to just remove the brackets $(\cdot)^{1/r}$ and where does the $c_n$ come from (in the term $|c_n-c|^rE|X^r|$)? Why does the right hand side of this converge to zero?

Comment: Are you sure that you stated the problem and the hint correctly? In general, $X$ doesn't need to be integrable, and so it doesn't make sense to approach the problem this way.

Comment: Yes, I checked several times. However, I did forget to write that $n\to\infty$. I've corrected that above.

Comment: Ok, so how should I approach the problem then?

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1544449/36150 ... it is somewhat more general than yours; simply set $Y_n :=c_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by saz the hint is bad. You can prove this from definition of convergence in probability as follows :choose $n$ such that $c_n <c+1$. Then $P\{|c_nX_n-cX|>\epsilon\} \leq P\{|c_n(X_n-X)|>\epsilon /2\}+P\{|(c_n-c)X|>\epsilon/2\}$. First term is $\leq P\{|X_n-X|>\epsilon /{2c_n}\} \leq  P\{|X_n-X|>\epsilon /{2(c+1)}\} \to 0$. Second term is $\leq P\{|X|>\frac {\epsilon} {|c_n-c|}\} \to 0$ because $\frac {\epsilon} {|c_n-c|} \to \infty$..